# Questions about the words 「いくつ」and 「あってもたりゃ」

Tags: words, manga

It is a situation when a worker noticed that one of his colleagues is working all day and all night without taking a rest. He then said the following:

> それじゃ**いくつ**からだが**あってもたりゃ**しねえ。

Then his hard-working colleague said this:

> なあにおれのからだは人一倍がんじょうだから...

Questions:

1. Is the sentence 「それじゃ...」 a question or just an opinion or something else? could it always be a question if it contains the word 「いくつ」?
2. What does the word 「あってもたりゃ」 mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Is the sentence それじゃ... a question or just an opinion or something else? could it always be a question if it contains the word いくつ?

It is a statement, not a question.

Whether or not 「いくつ」 makes the sentence a question depends on the other words used (and the sentence structure).

「いくつからだがあっても」 here means "***no matter how many bodies you've got***"

> 2. What does the word 「あってもたりゃ」mean?

「あってもたりゃしねえ」(Kanto tough guy speech)

=「あっても[足]{た}りはしない」(Dictionary form of above)

=「あっても足りない」(Simplified)

= "will never be enough"  「足りる」 means "to be satisfactory in quantity"

The first sentence means:

***"That way (← "If you work like that"), no matter how many bodies you've got, it won't be enough!"***